# Processing alpha blending in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, processing, argb

I'm working on processing and I'd like to recreate on low level code the function 
blend lightest.

I saw in documentation that `C = max(A * factor, B)`

- `C` is the returned color
- `A` is the source
- `B` is the image to mix with

I've seen on web that the factor specified is based on the alpha component of the source pixel, which is represented by the first 8 bits ( from the left ) of the 32-bit integer representing the pixel color. These leftmost bits are also referred to as the highest bits.

Source: [this book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=TKgfVpWPb0sC&pg=PA463&lpg=PA463&dq=C%20=%20max%28A%2afactor,%20B%29%20processing&source=bl&ots=pNHzVwA2kI&sig=gtyovWBGUXFRAmaqRPQ5VfeYHr8&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=sDqJUIKUHeOq0QWy9YHYBA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=C%20=%20max%28A%2afactor,%20B%29%20processing&f=false), page 464

What should i think of it?

This is my code of that part:

```
for (int y = 0; y < capWidth * capHeight; y++) {
    int factor = (pixels[y] >> 24) & 0xFF;
    pixels[y] = max(pixels[y] * factor, previousFrame.pixels[y]);      
}
```

That doesn't work, any help?

Comment: defines `it doesnt work`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each color: C = A(a/255) + B(1-(a/255)), where:

A is the foreground value,

B is the background value,

C is the resultant value, and

a is the alpha component.

This is per the alpha blending wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending

Answer (score 0):

1. this won't work because the `factor` in your original formula is a floating-point number between 0 and 1, and the `factor` in your code is an integer from 0 to 255.
2. this isn't a formula for blending, not really. For blending you have to *add* the colors, not take the maximum

Comment: ok ! 

so how should i interpret this ?

C = max(A * factor, B)

this is the formula for blend lightest pixel.
The documentation on processing website dont give more tips about it :/

Comment: as I said, you have to convert `factor` to a different range. In this case it means dividing it by 255.0 and storing as a `float`, rather than `int`. As far as I can see, your implementation is otherwise correct provided you're trying to achieve what's referred to as "LIGHTEST" mode in the book you cite.

Answer (score 0):

http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/index.html

I got it in here, the SVG processing javadoc for blending Lighten ! 
Well !